# Ajax after does not work bind event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I using Jquery with ajax.
I doing after click,unbind and after ajax bind click.
but Bind method not working.
Please help me

```
$(".lang").on("click", function (e) {

    $(this).unbind('click');

    if ($(this).hasClass("disabledLanguage")) {

        return false;
    }
    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Host + "Language",
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, Code: $(this).data("code") },
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.IsCompleted) {

                //window.location = window.location.href;
            }
            else {
                //alert("Error");
            }

            $(this).unbind('click'); //<----Notworking
        }
    });
      return false;

    });
```

Comment: `this`, in the ajax success callback, is not what you think it is - `var _this=this` before the ajax call, then `$(_this).unbind` in the success callback ... then learn about how `this` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * make a function to handle the click event stand alone
 * it's good for reuse and test
 */
function clickHandler(e){
    /**
     * cache the result of $(this)
     * for performance and reuse in another function context
     */
    var $lang = $(this);

    $lang.unbind('click', clickHandler);

    if ($lang.hasClass("disabledLanguage")) {
        return false;
    }

    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Host + "Language",
        data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, Code: $lang.data("code") },
        success: function(data) {

            if (data.IsCompleted) {

                //window.location = window.location.href;
            } else {
                //alert("Error");
            }

            /**
             * doing after click,unbind and after ajax bind click
             * so it should be bind click but not unbind click
             */
            $lang.bind('click', clickHandler);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$(".lang").on("click", clickHandler);
```

May be this can help you, and more detail in the comments